# Ionic: How to switch position of right nav button to left according to reading direction?

Tags: ionic-framework, right-to-left

I created a multilingual app. Supported languages are English, German and Arabic. So I have the trouble of changing reading directions.

I tried to solve this by changing the direction via css class in the body.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-class="language == 'ar' ? 'right_to_left' : 'left_to_right'">
```

css:

```
.right_to_left  {
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}

.left_to_right  {
  direction: ltr;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

I have a back button and a more button in the nav bar. I would like to have the nav button on one side and the more button on the other side.

In case I put just the more button on the left side changing direction, changes the side of the button as expected. But I want to have the more button on the right sight when reading direction is left to right and the oposite for right to left. However in this case the button is always on the right side and they are both in the same place.

[image]

How to get the back button on the left, more button on the right and changing sides when changing reading direction?

What have I done so far:

- put nav-buttons for both sides and tried to hide in case `language == 'ar'` or `language != 'ar'` => shows both buttons. (language is in rootScope)
- used `<ion-nav-buttons side="primary">`and `secondary` ([Doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavButtons/))